# How do I proceed Calculating. $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos ( \frac{\cos x}{1+2 \cos x}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I proceed to integrate 
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \arccos \left( \frac{\cos x}{1+2 \cos x}\right) dx
$$
The question is complete..looking forward for any help.....

Comment: what have u tried? Any own thoughts...

Comment: Looks like $\frac{5\pi^2}{24}$...

Comment: It also appears that $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/3} \arccos \left( \frac{\cos x}{1+2 \cos x}\right) dx=\frac{2\pi^2}{15},\,\int_0^{\pi/5} \arccos \left( \frac{\cos x}{1+2 \cos x}\right) dx=\frac{71\pi^2}{900},\,\int_0^{3\pi/5} \arccos \left( \frac{\cos x}{1+2 \cos x}\right) dx=\frac{241\pi^2}{900}.$

Comment: I can't even think how to proceed

Comment: @Vladimir Reshnetnokoy your answer is correct but can you please show the working........

Comment: @ADITYA This looks like one of Coxeter's integrals. These can be tricky to solve from scratch, but fortunately there is a lot of information about them on the Internet.

Comment: @ David H thanks found it on internet....